# Typing Generic Actions in Redux

Tags: typescript, redux

In my redux store, I have a number of state slices that are almost identical:

```
{
  cars: { fetching: false, data: [], error: '' },
  buses: { fetching: false, data: [], error: '' },
  bicycles: { fetching: false, data: [], error: '' }
}
```

I want to have actions like:

```
const requestCars = {
  type: 'REQUEST::cars',
  brand: 'Toyota'
}

const errorBuses = {
  type: 'ERROR::buses',
  error: 'An error'
}
```

I can generate actions instead of explicitly declaring each one:

```
const requestAction = (vehicle: string) => ({
  type: `REQUEST::${vehicle}`
})
```

My reducer then looks like:

```
const makeReducer = (vehicle: string) => (state, action) => {

  // I want to capture any action that has type REQUEST:vehicle

  switch(action.type) {
    case // problem is here
  }
}
```

So that my root reducer is:

```
{
  cars: makeReducer('cars'),
  buses: makeReducer('buses'),
  bicycles: makeReducer('bicycles')
}
```

So in `makeReducer(vehicle)`, I actually need to capture all actions with the type `REQUEST::${vehicle}` indiscriminately (say to set `fetching` to `true`).

The canonical example is to make use of tagged union types, but I can't because `action.type` has no literal type. So within the switch case, TypeScript does not allow me to access `action.brand`. I also can't use type guards because there are no discriminant properties in my action. Is there any way to achieve this without maintaining a list of string literals for the types?

**[EDIT]** - So it turns out this approach is seriously misguided because it will set the `fetching` state to true for all the vehicles when dispatching the action for one vehicle type. I guess I confused myself over the fact that while the `state` is narrowed before being passed into the reducer, *all* actions are passed through it. However I'm going to leave this up for posterity in the rare (?) case you need to listen to all actions that satisfy a particular condition in a single reducer.

In this case the solution is to use a type guard and thus the accepted answer.

Comment: Why is the `vehicle` part of the action type? It looks to me that this should be part of the action payload.

Comment: I’m using redux-saga, and having the same action type causes unwanted cancellations if I dispatch two actions (one for `cars` and one for `buses`) one after the other. At the same time I *want* the cancellation if an action for one vehicle type is dispatched before the saga of the previous same vehicle type hasn’t ended.

Comment: Why can't you use a type guard ? Like so : `const makeReducer = (vehicle: string) => (state: any, action: {type: string}) => {
    if(isRequest(action)){
        console.log(action.brand);
    }
}

function isRequest(action: {type: string}) : action is { type: string, brand: string } {
    return action.type.startsWith("REQUEST::");
}`

Comment: I tried that but it didn't seem to work - the action was typed to `never` outside the type guard which suggests it was matching all actions but I may have been overlooking something.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir This appears to work, I must have been doing something wrong earlier. Happy to accept a formatted version of this comment.

Comment: @ThomasChia ok, I will add one as soon as I get to the computer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `type` is not a string constant you can't use a tagged union as their type guard behavior relied on string literal types to work.

You could however use a custom type guard to check if the action is a request:

```
const makeReducer = (vehicle: string) => (state: any, action: {type: string}) => 
{ 
    if(isRequest(action)){ 
        console.log(action.brand); 
    } 
} 
function isRequest(action: {type: string}) : action is { type: string, brand: string } 
{ 
    return action.type.startsWith("REQUEST::"); 
}
```

Comment: My original implementation was slightly flawed - I can't switch indiscriminately on any `"REQUEST::` type since it would update for all vehicles which is what I don't want. However I'll leave this up as answer to the general question of how to do complex type narrowing.

Comment: @ThomasChia If you post new question with a more complete example, we can have a look :)

Comment: Thanks, but what I was trying to do was ultimately wrong anyway (I've edited the original question). Your answer is correct for the question, it's just that the question was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

why not make your `makeReducer` function take a more complex object then just the vehicule type name?

```
carType = {
   name: 'car',
   requestType : requestAction('car').type
}
```

and then:

```
makeReducer(carType)
```

and then

```
const makeReducer = (vehicleType) => (state, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case vehicleType.requestType:
        //do your thing
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that TypeScript cannot infer the specific action object, because `vehicleType.requestType` is dynamic. Therefore within the switch case, when I try to do `action.brand` I get a compiler error as TS thinks that the action may be an error type (which has no `brand` key).

Comment: I don't know TS much, but can't you use an interface `vehicleType` and have the types implement it so that type checking will work?

Comment: If I had that interface, it would have to have `type: string`, since each vehicle has a different action type. This means that I can't use the interface to do type narrowing because *all* types are `string`s. In the switch case, TS still cannot know which specific action I have. The alternative is a union of string literals which I was hoping to avoid but maybe this is not in the spirit of TS.

Comment: Well if TS is not helping you in this specific case, it might be better to just go _untyped_.